# Assembly language program to separate even and prime numbers using subroutines

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, subroutine

I wish to generate an assembly language program to separate even and prime numbers from a given list of numbers.
The program should make use of subroutines, stack and indirect addressing mode.

What I have tried is

```
.model small
  .data
     num db 0,13,4,7,8,9,14,15,2,10,19,20
     even dw 20 dup ?
     prime dw 20 dup ?

 .code
   mov ax, @ data
   mov ds, ax
   LEA BX,num
   LEA SI, even
   LEA DI, prime
   mov dh,02
L1:
   mov ah,00
   mov al, [BX]
   mov dl, al
   div dh
    cmp ah,00
    JE EVEN
EVEN:
     mov [SI], dl
     INC SI
     INC BX
     LOOP L1
```

As I am a beginner to assembly language, I wish to know the correct code for the above requirement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're having trouble with, so you need to narrow down your question. Also, why are `even` and `prime` word arrays when `num` is a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program should make use of subroutines

What your program must then do is run over the *num* array and call upon 2 subroutines, one that finds out if the number is prime and one that finds out if the number is even.
Currently you almost got a good loop, were it not that you forgot to initialize the `CX` register that the `LOOP` instruction depends on!

This is already a good loop:

```
    lea     bx, num
    lea     si, even
    lea     di, prime
    mov     cx, 12         ; There are 12 numbers in the 'num' array
L1:
    mov     al, [bx]
    call    TestForEven
    call    TestForPrime
    inc     bx
    loop    L1
```

Your test to find out if a number is even uses a division by 2. This is a wasteful solution! All you got to do is check if the lowest bit of the number is 0.

```
TestForEven:
    test    al, 1         ; This tests the lowest bit
    jnz     NotEven
    mov     [si], al      ; Adding to the 'even' array
    inc     si
NotEven:
    ret
```

Here are some tips to complete the task:

- Like [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288357/assembly-language-program-to-separate-even-and-prime-numbers-using-subroutines#comment108424112_61288357) wrote in his comment, you should have the *even* and *prime* arrays defined as bytes.
- If any number is found to be even, it can't be prime also. This means that you could make the call to *TestForPrime* from within *TestForEven* (instead of from the main loop).

  ```
  TestForEven:
      test    al, 1         ; This tests the lowest bit
      jnz     NotEven
      mov     [si], al      ; Adding to the 'even' array
      inc     si
      ret
  NotEven:
      call    TestForPrime
      ret
  ```

  And because this embedded call has now become what is called a tail-call, the `call` instruction is no longer needed:

  ```
  TestForEven:
      test    al, 1         ; This tests the lowest bit
      jnz     TestForPrime
      mov     [si], al      ; Adding to the 'even' array
      inc     si
      ret
  TestForPrime:
      ...
      ret
  ```
- If you search this forum (or google) you will certainly find good ways to test for a prime number. Good hunting...